# How to get id from array of Object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data in response so here `rcsaAssessmentData.data.lobCheckListDTOs` is array , riskAsesCklstSessionKey is property of array , How can i get this key using filter or any other option.Below console is printing all objects but i just want value for the `riskAsesCklstSessionKey`.

So far tried code...

array.js

```
var opChecklist = rcsaAssessmentData.data.lobCheckListDTOs.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.riskAsesCklstSessionKey;
  console.log("opcheclist...............",obj.riskAsesCklstSessionKey);
});

$scope.challengesDTO.addChlngToChklst= obj.riskAsesCklstSessionKey;
```

Comment: Where is your `array` ?

Comment: As i mentioned rcsaAssessmentData.data.lobCheckListDTOs is array of object

Comment: It's unclear what you want with `riskAsesCklstSessionKey`. If it's a property of the array then why not just `rcsaAssessmentData.data.riskAsesCklstSessionKey`?  And where is `obj` located?  It should have fallen out of scope after the `.filter` ended.

Comment: rcsaAssessmentData.data.riskAsesCklstSessionKey i can not implement just like this its in an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I think you mean:

You have an array of objects, rcsaAssessmentData.data.lobCheckListDTOs. Each of the objects in the array has a property called riskAsesCklstSessionKey. You are trying to get an array of those keys. If so, try this:

```
var keys = rcsaAssessmentData.data.lobCheckListDTOs.map(function(a) {return a.riskAsesCklstSessionKey;});
```

Comment: Dont you think its better to clarify instead of assuming things ?

Comment: @RayonDabre - Absolutely. However, if I feel that I understood the question (and I do in this case), there is no reason why I cannot answer it, while stating my assumptions. Worse case would be that I misunderstood the question that was being asked, but hopefully still provided an answer of value given the assumptions that I stated. I understand that this may not be everyone's point of view, and for that reason, I am willing to accept a down vote from time to time.